# How is type identity determined for interfaces or delegates

Tags: .net, interface, delegates, .net-assembly

If two different unrelated assemblies wish to use delegate and/or interface types (e.g.

```
interface IFoo {void Foo(); }
delegate void ActionByRef<T>(ref T param)_;
```

each for its own purposes, but it's possible that a third assembly which uses both of them might wish to pass objects between the two assemblies, what needs to happen for .net to decide that an `IFoo` or `ActionByRef<T>` exposed by one assembly should be accepted as input to the other?  I know that .net does not use simple structural equality for delegate types (meaning that e.g. a routine which expects a `Func<int,bool>` will not accept a `Predicate<int>`, even though both types represent functions with identical signatures), but what are the exact rules?  If one wishes to design an assembly to be compatible with .net 2.0 and 4.0, and have it accept a delegate for a method with three parameters, is there any way to define an `Action<T1,T2,T3>` such that the assembly will use its built-in one when linked into a .net 2.0 program, but will accept parameters of the framework-defined delegate of the same name when linked with .net 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

> what needs to happen for .net to decide that an IFoo or ActionByRef exposed by one assembly should be accepted as input to the other?

.NET will never accept an `IFoo` from assembly A where an `IFoo` from assembly B is expected. They're two different types, even if they happen to have the same name. You need to create an adapter between the two.

e.g. if you have a A.IFoo and need to pass it where a B.IFoo is expected, you can use this class:

```
class AToBFooAdapter : B.IFoo
{
    private readonly A.IFoo _foo;
    public AToBFooAdapter(A.IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _foo.Foo();
    }
}
```

For delegates it's easier; if they have the same signature, you can do that:

```
A.ActionByRef<string> action1 = ...
B.ActionByRef<string> action2 = new B.ActionByRef<string>(action1);
```

Comment: Does that mean that any time a strong-named assembly containing an interface or delegate is changed, whether or not anything is actually changed in the interface itself, all consumers of the interface or delegate must be recompiled to include the new strong name?  What happens if two interfaces in different strong-named assemblies need to make reference to each other?

Comment: Also, the delegate constructor syntax you specify sounds interesting, but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work; the constructor for a delegate type seems to insist upon receiving a method group rather than a delegate. While one could use a closure to wrap a delegate (e.g. `B.ActionByRef<string> action2; {A.ActionByRef<string> temp = action1; action2 = new B.ActionByRef<string>( (ref string st) => temp(ref st));}` it's source-ugly, it's inefficient, a separate converter code needs to be explicitly written for every pair of delegate types, and it's just plain nasty. Is there a better way?

Comment: @supercat, for your 1st question: if the strong name is changed, then yes, the consumers of this assembly will need to be recompiled. But since the strong name is the identity of the assembly, it isn't supposed to change...

Comment: For your second question: I just tried it, and it works for me (tested with C# 5, perhaps it doesn't work with earlier versions). You can also pass `action1.Invoke` to the constructor; since it's a method group, it should be accepted.

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong in the invocation; the syntax you give is much nicer than using a closure, and it's apt to be a bit more efficient, but it would still appear that one would end up needing a separate conversion method for every pair of delegate types or families one wishes to deal with; I also don't see any good way to avoid having delegates get more and more severely nested as they're passed around.

Comment: With regard to assemblies, how does one deal with assemblies that make use of each other?  Also, does the use of strong names mean that compiled assemblies becomes even more sacred than source code?  I guess I wish Microsoft had defined "partial strong names" for the public types which would be uniquely and repeatably computed based upon their public aspects and the partial strong names thereof, such that interfaces or delegates which had the same content (including names and namespaces), and contained identical members in the same order, would be considered identical.

Comment: @supercat, regarding "nested" delegates, here's how you can avoid it: `B.ActionByRef<string> action2 = (B.ActionByRef<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(B.ActionByRef<string>), action1.Target, action1.Method);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem regarding strongly named assemblies... As for considering "identical" types as the same type, that's called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) ; C# is a strongly typed language, and IMO it shouldn't allow things like that. What if the type changes in one assembly and not in the other?

Comment: I like your last suggestion, since it would works even with untyped delegates, thus allowing one to write things like a generic method `CombineActions<T>` which will join any two signature-compatible delegates into an `Action<T>` with proper support for contravariance (unlike `Delegate.Combine`, which pukes if given an `Action<BaseType>` and an `Action<DerivedType>`, the `CombineActions<DerivedType>` method would have no problem joining the such actions).  One slight caveat is that further handling would be required if the delegate is a product of `Delegate.Combine`.

Comment: From what I understand, if assembly 1 references assembly 2, and the strong name of assembly 2 changes, assembly 1 must be recompiled, changing its strong name.  If assembly 2 references assembly 1 and the strong name of assembly 1 changes, assembly 2 must be recompiled, changing its strong name.

Comment: BTW, I wonder what the pros or cons would have been of having a multi-targeted delegate return itself as the `Target` property and return a static (signature-specific) `RunMultiTargetDelegate` as the `Method`?  Had they done that, any delegate could be invoked by using its `Method` on its `Target`.  Also, I'm curious whether there's any particular reason delegate types don't define their own `Combine` methods?  If they did so, there would be no problem combining delegates which had different types but compatible signatures.